# how to get text from within a tag, but ignore other child tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am working with beautiful soup.
I have a html string:

```
<div><b>ignore this</b>get this</div>
```

How do I retrieve "get this", while ignoring "**ignore this**"

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get the `div` text just not recursively retrieving the children texts:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><b>ignore this</b>get this</div>')
>>> soup.div.find(text=True, recursive=False)
u'get this'
```

This works independently of the position of the text with respect of the children:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div>get this<b>ignore this</b></div>')
>>> soup.div.find(text=True, recursive=False)
u'get this'
```

Comment: Can I ask what the difference is between the first and second code snippets? It seems to me that they're the same two lines (with a minor typo in the second code snippet).

Comment: @AustinA The difference is in the html. It was to show how `recursive=False` gives you the text of the `div` ignoring children elements regardless of their position. (thanks, I fixed the `s` to `soup` typo in the second snippet :))

Comment: Yea, I see that now. I couldn't see that before for some reason. I do have a question here though. Let's say there are multiple div tags that I want to grab text from. `<div class="main"><div class="sub">Text1.<span>I don't want this text.</span></div><div class="sub">Text2.<span>I don't want this text either.</span></div></div>`. What I've been trying to do is use `soup.findAll('div','sub', recursive=False)` however this gives me an empty list whereas `soup.findAll('div','sub')` gives me `Text1. I don't want this text. Text2. I don't want this text either.` What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `find_all` returns a list of matches. You need to apply my solution to each matching div. Something like this: `' '.join(div.find(text=True, recursive=False) for div in soup.findAll('div', 'sub'))`. Then join all the texts in one string if you need.

Comment: @Austin.  if he helped you, can you give him a thumbs up on the answer?  It IS a good answer.   THanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getonlytext(s):
    beg_tag = s.find('<')
    while not beg_tag == -1:
        fin_tag = s.find('>')
        s = s.replace(s[beg_tag:fin_tag+1], '')
        beg_tag = s.find('<')
    return s
```