# Unable to extract text in the immediate level using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I followed this method to extract the text from the immediate level of a tag by using `find(text=True, recursive=False)` as mentioned in the another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195569/how-to-get-text-from-within-a-tag-but-ignore-other-child-tags), but for some particular markups like `u'<p>\n <strong>\n  Established\n </strong>\n 1865\n</p>\n'` it's not working:

Here's the code:

```
markup = u'<p>\n <strong>\n  Established\n </strong>\n 1865\n</p>\n'
s = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'lxml')
print s.find('p').find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

And it prints

```
45: u'\n'
```

It's working if I strip all the newlines `\n` from the markup it works good, but I don't think it's a good idea to just randomly strip all the newlines from the whole HTML file.

Any other solution ?

Comment: you can pre-process  html with regex to find all `\n` leading and trailing string then remove them

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns first match only. You need to use `find_all`:

```
print(s.find('p').find_all(text=True, recursive=False))
```

```
['\n', '\n 1865\n']
```

Deal with it as you need. For example, strip data and join pieces into final text:

```
data = s.find('p').find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
text = ' '.join(i.strip() for i in data)
print(text)
```

```
1865
```

Answer (score 0):

you can process your markup **once**  before using with `bs4` then `find` work fine for all tags

first make regex pattern:`r = re.compile('(^[\s]+)|([\s]+$)', re.MULTILINE)`

second remove leading and trailing spaces `markup = re.sub(r, '', markup)`

third replace new lines with spaces `markup = re.sub('\n', ' ', markup)`

fourth remove white spaces before open tags `markup = re.sub('[\s]+<', '<', markup)`

fifth remove white spaces after close tags `markup = re.sub('>[\s]+', '>', markup)`

putting all together :

```
>>> def pre_html(markup):
         r = re.compile('(^[\s]+)|([\s]+$)', re.MULTILINE)
         markup = re.sub(r, '', markup)
         markup = re.sub('\n', ' ', markup)
         markup = re.sub('[\s]+<', '<', markup)
         markup = re.sub('>[\s]+', '>', markup)
         return markup


>>> markup = u'<p>\n <strong>\n  Established\n </strong>\n 1865\n</p>\n'
>>> pre_html(markup)
u'<p><strong>Established</strong>1865</p>'
```

then your code should work fine like this :

```
>>> markup = u'<p>\n <strong>\n  Established\n </strong>\n 1865\n</p>\n'
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(pre_html(markup),"html.parser")
>>> soup.find('p').find(text=True, recursive=False)
u'1865'
```