# BS4 Get text from within all DIV tags but not children

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am crawling multiple webpages but am having an issue with some websites that have content/text with div tags rather than p or span. Previously the script worked fine getting text from p and span tags however if a snippet of the code is like the below:

```
<div>Hello<p>this is a test</p></div>
```

Using find_all('div') and .getText() provides the following output:

```
Hello this is a test
```

I am looking to get the result of just Hello. This will allow me to determine what content is in what tags. I have tried using recursive=False however this doesn't appear to function on a whole webpage with multiple div tags that have content in.

ADDED SNIPPET OF CODE

```
req = urllib.request.Request("https://www.healthline.com/health/fitness-exercise/pushups-everyday", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8").lower()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divTag = soup.find_all('div')
text = []
for div in divTag:
    i = div.getText()
    text.append(i)
print(text)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @usr2564301 Hey, I have added a snippet as the code is really large so just pulled what is needed into here. I have used healthline.com as an example however they don't appear to have any text laying in any DIV tags so i believe this output should be empty however it outputs everything.

Comment: I think you might be looking for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757377/how-to-remove-content-in-nested-tags-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your information this is answered here: [how to get text from within a tag, but ignore other child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195569/how-to-get-text-from-within-a-tag-but-ignore-other-child-tags)

this would lead to something  like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(div.find(text=True, recursive=False))
```

EDIT:
you just have to change

```
i = div.getText()
```

to

```
i = div.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Comment: @bb4L Thanks this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, we extract all 'p's from soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "<div>Hello<p>this is a test</p></div>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find('p'):
    p.extract()
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: good day dear Sri - many many thanks for your solution  - this looks interesting. Thanks for sharing it with us.