# How to only select certain p tags without children?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am new to the beautifulSoup and here is a naive question I have when I want to scrape some information on university course websites. The html is as followed and I'd like to get the text between tags p but not tags p which have some children like `<strong> and <em>`

The text desired:This course introduces....

Really appreciate your help!

```
<p>
<strong>MSDS 402 Introduction to Data Science</strong>
</p >
<p>This course introduces.....</p >
<p>
<em>Prerequisites: None.</em>
</p >
<p><a aria-label="MSDS 402-DL Section, ID#: 4765" class="link-list" href=" ">View MSDS 402-DL Sections</a ></p >
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995116/only-extracting-text-from-this-element-not-its-children

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27195960/4985099), try this ```[x.string for x in soup.findAll("p") if x.string]```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selector `p:not(:has(*))` that will select tags `<p>` without any children tags.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<p>
<strong>MSDS 402 Introduction to Data Science</strong>
</p >
<p>This course introduces.....</p >
<p>
<em>Prerequisites: None.</em>
</p >
<p><a aria-label="MSDS 402-DL Section, ID#: 4765" class="link-list" href=" ">View MSDS 402-DL Sections</a ></p >'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.select('p:not(:has(*))'):
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```
<p>This course introduces.....</p>
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thanks for this answer! Although I am not familiar with css, this method works out! Thanks!!